# Not able to invalidate bearer token using Twitter API

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-oauth, bearer-token

I am working on a new Twitter App. It is a WordPress plugin I am building. Working with Oauth2 bearer tokens. I could generate it alright. And it is fetching tweets as expected.

However, I also want to build the feature to "invalidate bearer tokens" into my plugin.

The plugin owner will use their own credentials (Twitter API key & secret) that they will get from Twitter directly.

When I try to "invalidate the bearer token", I get this response from Twitter:

> "{"errors":[{"code":348,"message":"Client application is not permitted
>   to to invalidate this token."}]}"
>
> response: { code: "401", message: "Unauthorized" },

```
$url_encoded_consumer_key = urlencode( $consumer_key );
$url_encoded_consumer_secret = urlencode( $consumer_secret );
$basic_auth_string = $url_encoded_consumer_key . ':' . $url_encoded_consumer_secret;
$base64_encoded_basic_auth_string = base64_encode( $basic_auth_string );

        $args = array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'httpversion' => '1.1',
                'headers' => array(
                    'authorization' => 'Basic ' . $base64_encoded_basic_auth_string,
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
                ),
                'body' => array(
                    'access_token' => $bearer_token
                )
            );
        /* Sending the values & retrieving the response object from Twitter */
        $response = wp_remote_post( 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/invalidate_token', $args );
$body = json_decode( $response['body'] );
```

Instead of invalidating the bearer token. It is showing me "401 Unauthorized" error.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?